# How to count correct answers in python?

Tags: python, count

I'm VERY new to programming (as in, in an intro class) and python. My assignment is to prompt a user to answer math questions, count the number they got correct/incorrect, calculate/display their numeric grade, and display their letter grade.

Everything seems to be working fine.. except I can't figure out how to get it to count the number of correct/incorrect answers. Any help?

```
def main():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    ans = int(input("What is 4 + 5? "))
    val = add(4, 5)
    if(ans == val):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans2 = int(input("What is 20 * 6? "))
    val2 = mult(20, 6)
    if(ans2 == val2):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans3 = int(input("What is 14 - 10? "))
    val3 = sub(14, 10)
    if(ans3 == val3):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans4 = int(input("What is 30 / 5? "))
    val4 = div(30, 5)
    if(ans4 == val4):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans5 = int(input("What is 29 + 2? "))
    val5 = add(29, 2)
    if(ans5 == val5):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans6 = int(input("What is 50 - 10? "))
    val6= sub(50, 10)
    if(ans6 == val6):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans7 = int(input("What is 5 * 11? "))
    val7 = mult(5, 11)
    if(ans7 == val7):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans8 = int(input("What is 9 / 3? "))
    val8 = div(9, 3)
    if(ans8 == val8):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans9 = int(input("What is 90 - 5? "))
    val9 = sub(90, 5)
    if(ans9 == val9):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    ans10 = int(input("What is 412 + 5? "))
    val10 = add(412, 5)
    if(ans10 == val10):
        correct + 1
    else:
        incorrect + 1
    print()
    print("Thanks, " + str(name) + "!")
    print()
    print("Correct " + str(correct))
    print()
    print("Incorrect " + str(incorrect))
    print()
    calcGrade(correct)

def add(value, value2):
    return value + value2

def sub(value, value2):
    return value - value2

def mult(value, value2):
    return value * value2

def div(value, value2):
    return value / value2

def calcGrade(correct):
    grade = (correct * 100)/ 10
    print("Numeric Grade " + str(grade))
    if(grade > 90):
        letterGrade = "A"
    if(grade > 80):
        letterGrade = "B"
    if(grade < 70):
        letterGrade = "C"
    if(grade < 69):
        letterGrade = "F"
    print()
    print("Letter Grade " + str(letterGrade))

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `correct + 1` you are evaluating what `correct` plus one is equal to, but you aren't updating the value stored in `correct`.

What you want to put instead is `correct = correct + 1`. Or, more succinctly, `correct += 1`.

The same applies to `incorrect`.

Answer (score 0):

Every programming language has some specific features which you can use for different purposes. In Python, there is this function called `eval()` which is very useful for your case ...

Here is an example if its use:

```
In [2]: eval('2*3'), eval('12+13'), eval('30/5')
Out[2]: (6, 25, 6)
```

Notice that you do the same set of operations many times:

- Print a prompt
- Input a number
- evaluate another number
- see of the two numbers are equal
- increment respective counters

In Python (or in many other languages), these would be done in a loop. For this, you need to create a list if things you want to loop over. The list will look like this:

```
In [4]: qns
Out[4]:
['4+5',
 '20*6',
 '14-10',
 '30/5',
 '29+2',
 '50-10',
 '5*11',
 '9/3',
 '90-5',
 '412+5']
```

At this point, you can use something called *list comprehension* to get *all* the results ...

```
In [5]: [input('what is ' + q + '?')  for q in qns ]
what is 4+5?9
what is 20*6?12
what is 14-10?34
what is 30/5?6
what is 29+2?31
what is 50-10?40
what is 5*11?50
what is 9/3?2
what is 90-5?85
what is 412+5?417
Out[5]: [9, 12, 34, 6, 31, 40, 50, 2, 85, 417]
```

Now you need to compare them with the actual values. You can actually put the comparison within the list comprehension into a single operation.

```
In [6]: results = [input('what is ' + q + '?') == eval(q)  for q in qns ]
what is 4+5?9
what is 20*6?12
what is 14-10?34
what is 30/5?6
what is 29+2?31
what is 50-10?40
what is 5*11?50
what is 9/3?2
what is 90-5?85
what is 412+5?417

In [7]: results
Out[7]: [True, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True]
```

In Python, it turns out that `True == 1` and `False == 0` for *some* cases. *Which* cases you ask? Well, that's something that comes with experience in something called *duck typing*. So in a couple of months, with enough experience, you will find the answer to "which cases" almost trivial. Anyway, because of this phenomenon, you can count the right answers as:

```
In [8]: sum(results)
Out[8]: 6
```

And the incorrect answers?

```
In [9]: len(qns) - sum(results)
Out[9]: 4
```

Cheers, and happy programing!

Comment: Hate to say it but I am expecting you to get shelled for daring to suggest `eval`  :^)

Comment: The only saving grace I guess is that `eval` is performed in a predefined list of strings hard coed in, and not on a user-supplied string :). But I get the issue people will have with `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

you have some mistakes with your code. Please try to this. correct +=1 or correct = correct + 1 and incorrect -=1 and incorrect = incorrect - 1

Answer (score 0):

```
correct = correct + 1
incorrect = incorrect + 1
```

By doing this, the current value of the correct/incorrect answers is incremented and stored in the same variable, basically, this is a counter, for the number of correct and incorrect answers